# How to make a CheckBoxList have unique items when a new item is added to it?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a `DropDownList` with items like:

1. BEDROOM
2. KITCHEN
3. BATHROOM
4. LIVING_HALL......etc..

I have a `TextBox` which accept only number.

For example if I select **BEDROOM** from the `DropDownList` and if I type any number in the `TextBox` for eg. **2**, the selected item in the `DropDownList` and will get concatenated with the number which is put in a loop, and on button_click items are added one by one to the `CheckBoxList` like:

1. BEDROOM1
2. BEDROOM2

The .cs code I have written is:

```
protected void Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
            int q1 = Convert.ToInt16(TextBox1.Text);
            for (int i = 1; i <= q1; i++)
            {
                string t1 = DropDownList1.SelectedItem.ToString().Trim();
                CheckBoxList1.Items.Add(string.Concat(t1, i));
            }
            TextBox1.Text = "";
    }
```

Similarly the same procedure is followed with other items in `DropDownList`. Like if **KITCHEN** is selected and number in the `TextBox` is **3**. On button_click,items like:

1. KITCHEN1
2. KITCHEN2
3. KITCHEN3 is added to the `CheckBoxList`.

From above example my `CheckBoxList` will look something like:

1. BEDROOM1
2. BEDROOM2
3. KITCHEN1
4. KITCHEN2
5. KITCHEN3

So now my problem is after added KITCHEN item in the List, I want to again add one BEDROOM.

So if I select BEDROOM from the `DropDownList` and type **1** in the `TextBox`, and on button_click, I want **BEDROOM4** to be added to the `CheckBoxList`. But **BEDROOM1** adds again according to my code.

Kindly Kindly help...thank you in advance.

Comment: instead of `int i` take `static int i`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rewrite your handler to something like this:

```
protected void Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int q1 = Convert.ToInt16(TextBox1.Text);

    string t1 = DropDownList1.SelectedItem.ToString().Trim();
    int start = 1;
    string checkBoxValue = string.Concat(t1, start);
    while (CheckBoxList1.Items.Cointains(new ListItem(checkBoxValue)))
    {
        start++;
        checkBoxValue = string.Concat(t1, start);
    }

    for (int i = start; i <= start + q1 - 1; i++)
    {
        CheckBoxList1.Items.Add(string.Concat(t1, i));
    }

    TextBox1.Text = "";
}
```

Essentially we are just checking for each incrementing value whether such an element presents in the check box list collection. As soon as the absent value is found, we are adding the requested range of values, just as before.

Comment: In the code that you have given, if I select BEDROOM from `DropDownList` and add 2 in the `TextBox`, then on button_click BEDROOM1, BEDROOM2, BEDROOM3 is getting added.

Comment: @ArchanaB.R, sorry, little typo in `for`. Please see the updated code

Answer (score 0):

Before concatenating a new item first check it exist or not
For example you select BEDROOM on the dropdown and there are already 3 BEDROOM items in the dropdownlist. Now first check BEDROOM1 exist in the dropdown or not ? If yes then increment the no from 1 to 2 like BEDROOM1 to BEDROOM2 if it exists then again increment the number......
you can easily check the item as

```
  bool check = DropDownList1.Items.Contains(new ListItem("name", "value"));
  if( check )
  {
      string t1 = DropDownList1.SelectedItem.ToString().Trim();
        CheckBoxList1.Items.Add(string.Concat(t1, i));
  }
  else
  {
      // again concatenate a new item 
    }
```

Just add the above line before

Comment: Where exactly am I suppose to fit this.